# Sobolev space,notation

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

There are two notions of Sobolev space: $H_0^{k,p}(\Omega)$ and $H^{k,p}(\Omega)$ as a closure of $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ and $C^\infty(\Omega)$,
respectively,w.r.t. $\|\cdot\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}$. In my source the definitions of $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ and $C^\infty(\Omega)$ have been omitted. What do they mean by this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C^\infty(\Omega)$ denotes the set of all infinitely differentiable real-valued functions defined on $\Omega$.

$C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ denotes the set of all functions in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ that vanish off a compact subset of $\Omega$.

Comment: It is worth noting, I think, that $C_0^\infty$ is a little ambiguous.  For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Functional_analysis) suggests $C_c^\infty$ for smooth functions with compact support, and $C_0^\infty$ for smooth functions that vanish at infinity (i.e. on the boundary).

Comment: Yes, but the context is Sobolev spaces. If $H_0^{k,p}$ is defined as the closure of $C_0^\infty$, it is compactly supported smooth functions that are meant.

Answer (score 3):

- $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is the space of all functions that are smooth (infinitely continuously differentiabl) on $\Omega$, for example 
  $$ C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C} \;\middle|\;  \text{$f^{(n)}$ exists for all $n$} \right\}. $$
- $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is a little ambiguous, and could mean a couple of things, depending on the author.  To some authors, it means the space of smooth which tend to zero on the boundary.  For example,
  $$ C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C} \;\middle|\;  \text{$f^{(n)}$ exists for all $n$ and $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} f(x) = 0$} \right\}. $$
  In my experience, this is the more common meaning of the notation.

  That being said, other authors will take $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ to denote the set of all smooth functions which have compact support in $\Omega$.  That is, $f\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ if
  $$ \operatorname{supp}(f) = \overline{ \{x\in \Omega : f(x) \ne 0 \}} $$
  is a compact subset of $\Omega$.  You will sometimes see the notation
  $$ \operatorname{supp}(f) \Subset \Omega \qquad\text{or}\qquad \operatorname{supp}(f) \subset\subset \Omega, $$
  which can be read as "the support of $f$ is compactly contained in $\Omega$."  Essentially, this ensures that functions which are compactly supported in $\Omega$ vanish at the boundary, so that the space of compactly supported functions is contained in the space of functions which vanish at the boundary.

  You will also see this space denoted by $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, and the potential ambiguity suggests that you should check whatever book or paper you are reading for some clarification here.  If you are lucky, there is an index of notation used somewhere.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I've just notice your remark that it should be a compact subset of $\Omega$, but I do not understand what difference it makes. Can you please explain this to me?

Comment: @user122424 Take for instance $\Omega$ to be the unit ball and $f \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ to be the function that is identically $1$. The support of $f$ is $\overline \Omega$, which is compact. However, the support is not a subset of $\Omega$ and $f \notin C_0^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: @user122424 While Umberto P. has already answered the question, let me add that if $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ denotes the space of smooth functions which vanish on the boundary and $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is the set of compactly supported smooth functions, then we want $C_c^\infty(\Omega) \subseteq C_0^\infty(\Omega)$.  So a compactly supported function must also vanish at the boundary.  Umberto P. gives an example of a function that is smooth and compactly supported, but which does not vanish on the boundary.